# Connecting various process attributes reported by top, ps, /proc/pid/statm, /proc/pid/status, /proc/pid/smaps

Tags: linux, bash, memory, proc

Here are some of the common attributes I figured out:

top(VIRT) , smem(VSS), /proc/pid/statm (1st entry in pages), /proc/pid/status (VmSize), ps(VSZ)

top(RES) , smem(RSS), /proc/pid/statm (2nd entry in pages), /proc/pid/status (VmRSS), add all Rss: values in /proc/pid/smaps process mappings,  add all Private_.* + Shared_.* values in /proc/pid/smaps process mappings, ps(RSS)

top(DATA) , **not reported by smem**, /proc/pid/statm (6th entry in pages), /proc/pid/status (VmData), **not reported by ps**

top(CODE) , **not reported by smem**, /proc/pid/statm (4th entry in pages), **not reported by /proc/pid/status**, **not reported by ps**

top(SHR) , **not reported by smem**, /proc/pid/statm (3rd entry in pages), **not reported by /proc/pid/status**, **not reported by ps**

smem(USS), add all Private_.* values in /proc/pid/smaps process mappings

smem(PSS), add all Pss: values in /proc/pid/smaps process mappings

smem(Swap), add all Swap: values in /proc/pid/smaps process mappings

top(SWAP) = top(VIRT) - top(RES)

**Question:**
Are there any other relations (as mentioned above) present that I have missed above? Can you share?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Added a note at the end.

Comment: I still don't see a question in there. No, this is not about the lack of a `?`. I mean that I don't understand what you expect an answer to consist of.

Comment: Like this? http://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/space/blog/linux/LinuxMemoryStats

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The programs ps, top, and smem are all getting their data from /proc. Maybe you'd enjoy looking at the source code to get the exact details. Those details have changed over the years and will probably continue to change.

The smem program is a Python script. Here is the list of fields in smem: http://selenic.com/repo/smem/file/43b299004079/smem#l271

Linux gets top and ps from package procps. Here is the list of fields in top: http://procps.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/procps/procps/top.c?revision=1.134&view=markup#l1223

And here is the list of fields in ps: http://procps.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/procps/procps/ps/output.c?revision=1.65&view=markup#l1286